# Wordpress RSSImport description character encoding issues

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, rss

I'm using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-import/) plugin for my Wordpress site and ever since I moved my site to a new server I've encountered very specific character encoding problems; It's solely restricted to my RSS feed's description (the titles are correctly encoded and so is all the other content on the site). I have tried to set "charsetscan" to true in order to force the correct character set but unfortunately without any success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include the name of the plugin in your question title and your description instead of just giving a link. Also try to clarify your problem. What characters are encoded wrong? Try to give an example.

Comment: It is included in my question title. The characters encoded wrong is in this case 'å', 'ä' & 'ö'.